# Socket.io Node.js error in IE7 - Access Denied

Tags: internet-explorer-7, node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io to connect to my node server using the following script:

```
$socket = new io.Socket(null,{port:8086,rememberTransport:false});  
$socket.connect();
```

If works fine in IE8/9, Chrome, Safari & FF.

When I try it in IE7, a connection is established but then the following error pops up:

```
An error has occured in the script on this page.
Error: Access denied.
```

The client is then disconnected from the node server.

I am runnig node.js V0.4.1.

Does any one have any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you disabled some transports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was caused because I did not have the `secure:true` statment in the io.connect. It should read:

```
 var socket = new io.Socket(null, {port: 443, secure: true, rememberTransport: false});
 socket.connect();
```